# Null Set use ball instead of interval for higher dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set): 
Suppose $A$ is a subset of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \{U_n \} (A \subset \bigcup_1 ^\infty U_n \ \text{and} \ \sum_1^\infty |U_n| < \epsilon )$
where the $U_n$ are intervals and $|U|$ is the length of $U$, then $A$ is a null set.

I believe the above definition generalizes to higher dimensions ($\mathbb{R}^n$)?

Can we use balls in the definition instead of intervals for higher dimensions?

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: @almagest For instance in $\mathbb{R}^2$ balls I believe are open discs (of a certain radius $r$), while intervals can be rectangles.

Comment: Sure. But in $\mathbb{R}$ the interval $(a,b)$ is the same as the ball $B(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{b-a}{2})$.

Comment: @almagest Sorry I mean for the generalization to higher dimensions, can we use balls instead of intervals?

Comment: Yes, of course.